# Loading GeoPoints / Path on MapView is taking forever. Any way to speed it up?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I am working with a custom MapView for an application. I have a database with a LOT of GPS datapoints saved and I am currently loading them using Overlays, then performing an .addAll on the MapView with the Overlays.

However, it is taking up to 2 minutes to load just a few hundred data points as a path on the MapView.

The code to load the Data Points is:

```
    private void loadMap() {        
    //Load the specific data from the database
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    try {
        db.open();
        Cursor mDataPoints = db.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM GPS_DATA)", null);
        if ((mDataPoints != null) && (!mDataPoints.isClosed()) && (mDataPoints.moveToFirst())) {                
            mapMain.setFinishedLoading(false);
            mapMain.getOverlays().clear();

            if ((!mDataPoints.isClosed()) && (mDataPoints.moveToFirst())) {
                while (!mDataPoints.isAfterLast()) {

                    this.drawPath(db, 
                                  DBAdapter.formatLong(mDataPoints, "data_id"), 
                                  DBAdapter.formatString(mDataPoints, "data_name"),
                                  DBAdapter.formatString(mDataPoints, "data_type"));                        

                    mDataPoints.moveToNext();
                }
            }

            mapMain.refreshDrawableState();
            mapMain.setEnabled(true);
        }
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
}

public void drawPath(DBAdapter db, long pDataID, String pDataName, String pDataType) {  

    Cursor mData = db.getPointDataByDataID(pDataID);
    if ((!mData.isClosed()) && (mData.moveToFirst())) {
        boolean vFirst = true;
        int i = 0;
        GeoPoint startGP;
        GeoPoint geoPoint1;
        GeoPoint geoPoint2 = null;

        while (!mData.isAfterLast()) {
            if (vFirst) {
                startGP = new GeoPoint((int) (DBAdapter.formatDouble(mData, "latitude") * 1E6), (int) (DBAdapter.formatDouble(mData, "longitude") * 1E6));
                mapMain.getOverlays().add(new Map_Route_Overlay(startGP, startGP, this.returnPathColor(pDataType), pDataName));
                vFirst = false;
                geoPoint2 = startGP;
            } else {
                geoPoint1 = geoPoint2;

                geoPoint2 = new GeoPoint((int) (DBAdapter.formatDouble(mData, "latitude") * 1E6), (int) (DBAdapter.formatDouble(mData, "longitude") * 1E6));
                if (geoPoint2.getLatitudeE6() != 22200000) {
                    mapMain.getOverlays().add(new Map_Route_Overlay(geoPoint1, geoPoint2, this.returnPathColor(pDataType), pDataName));
                }
            }

            i += 1;
            mData.moveToNext();
        }

        if (geoPoint2 != null) { 
            mapMain.getOverlays().add(new Map_Route_Overlay(geoPoint2, geoPoint2, this.returnDataColor(pDataType), pDataName));
        }
    }
    mData.close();
}
public int returnDataColor(String pType) {
    int vReturnData = Color.BLUE;

    if (pType.trim().equals("S")) {
        vReturnData = Color.RED;
    }

    return vReturnData;
}
```

And the code for the Map_Route_Overlay class is:

```
public final class Map_Route_Overlay extends Overlay {
  private static String TAG = CoreFunctions.APP_TAG + "_MapRouteOverlay";

  private GeoPoint geoPoint1;
  private GeoPoint geoPoint2;
  private int defaultColor = 999;
  private String dataName = "";

  public Map_Route_Overlay(GeoPoint pGeoPoint1, GeoPoint pGeoPoint2, int pColor, String pText) {
    this.geoPoint1 = pGeoPoint1;
    this.geoPoint2 = pGeoPoint2;
    this.defaultColor = pColor;
    this.dataName = pText;
  }

  public void setDataName(String pName) {
    this.dataName = pName;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean draw (Canvas canvas, MMMapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    if (shadow == false) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        Point point = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(this.geoPoint1, point);
        paint.setColor(this.defaultColor);
        Point point2 = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(this.geoPoint2, point2);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setAlpha(this.defaultColor == Color.parseColor("#6C8715")?220:120);
        canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x,point2.y, paint);
    }

    return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
  }
```

}

I have tried several options, including loading the data using Threads, but notifying the MapView to load the Overlays when completed was becoming a nightmare.

Just for reference, MMMapView is my custom MapView component, which for now just inherits MapView and implements two functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't be trying to display hundreds of Overlays on the screen at once, because you will get bad performance. Try limiting it to 10-20. Any more than that and it is too busy for the user anyway.

Also you should be using a thread to load the items from your database. What I do is I use a custom ItemizedOverlay, and add custom OverlayItems to it in a thread. Then once I am done loading I call `mapView.postInvalidate();` so that they are displayed on the screen.

Comment: I figured that trying to load that many Overlays was causing a severe performance issue. What I am trying to accomplish is draw a bunch of paths from the data I have in the database. The paths are broken down by unique id's which then have corresponding records in another database table, which could be between 10 GeoPoints or 200 GeoPoints (depending on the length of the path).

Comment: I'm not sure if this would make a difference, but could you just have one Overlay that represents and draws all the paths? It might make the performance difference

Answer (score 1):

I am using this: http://code.google.com/p/mapview-overlay-manager/

It provides LazyLoading to load only the visible markers on the map.

Comment: anyone have experience with this lib?  is it stable and decent performance?

Comment: I was using it only for my personal small projects, but tested for 1000 markers placed on 1 overlay and it was ok. I don't have any experience with different approaches so don't know how it stands among other.

Comment: Tried it, but it isn't very flexible.